# Stripe test data: single digit month failing validation

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

I have just implemented Stripe for payment processing within my application and everything seems okay, except one issue I just can't understand.

[I am using the test data listed here](https://stripe.com/docs/testing). Specifically, I send the following data:

[image]

[image]

The above two sets of data both fail:

[image]

If I change the month to be `10`, `11` or `12`, it works okay.

This issue holds true for all other test card numbers as well.

Comment: Are you using Stripe's PHP library?

Comment: @bcmcfc it looks like this is at the Stripe.js stage (before anything hits OP's server, PHP or otherwise). If this is the case, consider changing the tag from php to javascript...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

01/2014 is in the past. Stripe rejects expired expiry dates.

09/2014, 1/2015, etc will work (depending when you read this...)

Answer (score 0):

Single digit months are rejected by some payment gateways (Asseco, for example). If the month is 1, you have to post it as 01.